Are malted barley flour and malted barley powder the same thing?
The question originated with "malted barley flour" vs "malted barley powder", but I also see other variations in similar product descriptions/names:

malted barley flour
malted barley powder
diastatic malted barley flour
diastatic malt powder
dry malt powder

Which of these are different things and which are synonymous?

“Malted barley powder” is an ambiguous term, which might refer to either malted barley flour or to dry malt extract (aka dry malt powder), which is the result of spray-drying malt syrup. “Diastatic” is an adjective meaning that the stuff contains a significant amount of active diastase (aka amylase), but the term would not always be used.

The term diastatic means that the product still contains active Amylase enzymes.  These enzymes are able to break down starches into simple sugars.  This happens most quickly at warm temperatures ~50-70C.  At temperatures much higher than this, the enzymes themselves begin breaking down too.
But unless you are leaving the dough for a long time unrefrigerated, I would not expect too much conversion.  Any sugars might also be beneficially used-up by yeast.
There's a reasonable explanation here:  https://clockworklemon.com/what-is-malted-barley-flour/
But the top four are simply ground-to-flour malted barley.  "Dry Malt Powder" is probably dry malt extract - which is a powdered "malt sugar" made by using amylase enzymes on/from malt to make sugars, which are washed out with water, then dried to powder.

Brewer's perspective here.
Malted barley has a high percentage of starches and relatively small amounts of simple sugars.
Dry malt extract has a high percentage of simple sugars (and usually some more complex sugars as well).
If you are wanting to add starches to your recipe, use malted barley. If you are wanting to add sugars, use malt extract.
Malted barley naturally possesses significant diastatic power. If malted barley gets warm (140F - 160F) and moist/wet, the amylase activates and will rapidly (10-20 minutes) convert most of the starches to simple sugars (any starches that are present, not just from the malted barley).
Interestingly, there are two different variants of amylase that cleave the starches differently (random cuts vs. popping simple sugars off the end). These two enzymes exhibit maximum activity at different temperature and pH levels - brewers exploit this difference to affect the resultant non-fermentable mix of sugars that remain (which affects fermentability and mouthfeel of the resulting beer).
When producing dry malt extract, it is usually the case that all of the amylase is denatured due to time and temperature. However, there are some manufacturing processes that are fast and low-temperature enough to preserve some of the amylase (and thus maintain some diastatic power) in the finished product.
In the brewing world, the process of adding warm water to milled malted barley to convert starches to sugars is called "mashing." The process of separating the sweet water from the grain is called "lautering." The resulting sweet water is called "wort." Approximately 80% of the dry weight of the malted barley is extracted by this processes and is contained in the wort.
